# BizTalk looses port bindings when deploying

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-deployment

As the title says: every time I deploy from Visual Studio to BizTalk 2013 R2 the orchestration gets unbounded and unenlisted. The receive/send port looses its pipeline.

I have tried to clean cached bindings on `C:\Users\<your_user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\Deployment\BindingFiles`    and do a redeployment on everything, but no success.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Export the bindings before the deployment and re-import them after the deployment.

Another option is to install [BizTalk Deployment Framework](https://github.com/BTDF) which has an option to Quick Deploy, that just simply re-GACs the DLLs, useful for when making small changes to existing objects that don't need to update the BizTalk DB